# sorting with 3 categories

Tags: mysql, kohana

so here's the problem

I have 3 types for a hotel

1. premium
2. featured
3. basic

I am trying to display a list of hotels and sort them so that featured hotels are the first shown

what mysql query would accomplish this?

**EDIT**
here's the table, with some fields stripped

```
ID | hotel_name | type
=======================
1 | Aria Hotel | basic
```

Comment: How do your tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'featured', 'premium', 'basic')
```

You could rearrange `'featured', 'premium', 'basic'` upto your needs, and may also put `DESC` there too

For example

```
ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'featured', 'premium', 'basic') DESC
```

or to arrange the rest as normal sorting order.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'featured', 'premium', 'basic') DESC, type;
```

Comment: I can only use this function http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/database/builder#orderby

so, other than DESC and ASC, I have no other option

Comment: Imm, so could you specify "with Kohana" in your question title then? and also tag with `kohana`

Comment: I guess, you will end up by calling `->query` directly instead of `->orderby` method like `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'featured', 'premium', 'basic') DESC, type;");`

Comment: Nice. Is there a FIELD equivalent in MS SQL Server ?

Comment: @Ygam, the link you mention, has this code `$db->orderby(NULL, 'RAND()');` .. so, can you not use the FIELD() function that way?

Comment: the second parameter accepts only 3 strings, ASC, DESC, RAND(), RANDOM(), NULL as values. if anything other than that is specified, it defaults to ASC (I was reading code minutes ago)

Answer (score 0):

I will use group by on hotel type and sort by desc in your case. Try writing the query.